# Null Pointer excepción al tratar de ingresar una entrada en una base de datos

Tags: java, sqlite

El error surge en esta linea

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

El código completo es este

```
static String login = "";
static String password = "";
static String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\mas-v\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Clap Manager\\DataBases\\DBCLAPMAN";
Connection con = null;
String driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";

public Conexion() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        if (con != null) {
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion no realizada" + e);
    }
}

public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}

public void Desconectar() {
    con = null;
    if (con != null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se Cerro la conexion");
    }
}

public boolean registrar(Sector s) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection con = getCon();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO Sectores (Nombre, IDSector, Direccion) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    try {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, con);
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, s.getNombre());
        ps.setString(2, Integer.toString(s.getIDSector()));
        ps.setString(3, s.getDireccion());

        ps.execute();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "no se cerro" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Este código lo recicle de otro proyecto que ya había hecho y funcionaba perfectamente y ahora no se que pasa

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero que nada quiero remarcar que el código puede ser refactorizado y metodizado para una mayor legibilidad, usabilidad y escalabilidad del mismo.

Siguiendo lo anterior, por un lado implementaría un patrón *Singleton* que devuelva una sola conexión a la base de datos, de esta manera no se manejarían múltiples conexiones y se separaría la responsabilidad de conexión de la de persistencia propia de determinado objeto, para esta ultima etapa podría aplicarse un  patrón *DAO* o Data Access Model.

En tu caso quedaría algo como esto la conexion:

```
public class Singleton_ConexionSQLite {

    //CONSTANTE QUE INSTANCIA UNA NUEVA VERSIÓN DE LA CONEXIÓN CON LA BASE
    private static final Singleton_ConexionSQLite INSTANCE = new Singleton_ConexionSQLite();

    /*
    ****************************************************************************
    */
    //CONSTRUCTOR
    private Singleton_ConexionSQLite (){
            try {
                Class.forName("driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Singleton_ConexionSQLite.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }

    /*
    ****************************************************************************
    */
    //METODO QUE DEVUELVE LA INSTANCIA UNICA DE LA CLASE SINGLETON_SQLite
    public static Singleton_ConexionSQLite getSingleton_ConexionSQL() {
     return INSTANCE;
    }

    /*
    ****************************************************************************
    */
    //METODO PARA CONECTAR CON LA BASE
    public Connection getConexionSQL() throws SQLException {

        final String user = "sa";
        final String password = "1234";

        return DriverManager.getConnection("url", user, password);

    }

}
```

En cuanto al método que se encargará de la persistencia (el cual iría en una clase separada a la de conexión), quedaría de esta manera:

```
public void addSector(Sector s) {

    try (Connection con = Singleton_ConexionSQLite.getSingleton_ConexionSQL().getConexionSQL();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(INSERT);){

        stmt.setString(1, s.getNombre());
        stmt.setString(2, Integer.toString(s.getIDSector()));
        stmt.setString(3, s.getDireccion());

        if(nullChecker(s)){
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        } else {
            System.err.println("Algunos datos del sector son nulos, reviselo en :"
            + s.getNombre());
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaDB_LaClaseQueSea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    }
```

Vale recordar que la clase `Singleton_ConexionSQLite` posee un método y atributo estático por lo que no es necesario instanciar una version de su clase (siempre retornaremos la misma instancia ;) ).

Con el uso del **try with resources** nos olvidaremos de la responsabilidad de tener que cerrar la Connection y el PreparedStatement.

La validación if antes de ejecutar la query comprobará que no sean nulos lo campos

```
private static boolean nullChecker(Sector s) {
    return s.getNombre() != null && c.getIDSector() != null && c.getDireccion()!= null;
}
```

Espero te sirva! saludos.

Comment: mil gracias,  lo usaré de esa forma es mucho más práctico

Comment: Genial Marcel! a disfrutar de ese refactoring jaja saludos.